# By the term x y means z, what is the meaning of the word by in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The standard definitions of By says "agent performing the action", "do something before a certain time" etc.. but I am not able to understand what by means in this context.

Usage example in Kant's Critique of Pure Reason, "By the term 'knowledge a priori' therefore, we shall in the sequel understand...."

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English prepositions tend to have a wide variety of meanings, and this is particularly true of old prepositions like *by*, which came to the language from Old English, giving the word over one thousand years to gather meanings.  The *OED* finds 39 major categories of meaning for the preposition *by*, classified into seven classes of usage.  The one that's relevant here is in **class V**: "medium, means, instrumentality, agency", **category 29**: "After verbs of *knowing*, *perceiving*, *calling*, etc.", **subcategory b**: "In *understand by*, *mean by*".

Which is to say that in

> **by** the term 'knowledge a priori'... we understand....

the term *knowledge a priori* is the label to be given to the concept that follows.  (In this case, that's the kind of knowledge that's the opposite of *empirical knowledge*, the kind gained through experience). *By* here tell us that when we encounter the term, we're to understand it refers to the concept.